# Unconditional distribution of the length of a stick broken twice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A stick lies on the interval $[0,1]$, and is broken at the point $X$~$U(0,1)$. The left part is then broken again at the point $Y$~$U(0,X)$, i.e the pdf of $Y|X$ is
$f_{Y|X=x}(y)= \mathbb{I}_{[0,x]}1/x$. I'm trying to find the unconditional distribution of $Y$, this is what I did so far and I'm wondering what I am doing wrong since the last result is obviously unbounded:
$$P(Y<y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(Y<y|X=x)f_{X}(x)dx$$
$$= \int_0^1P(Y<y|X=x)\cdot 1 dx$$ 
$$= \int_0^1 1\int_0^y \frac{1}{x}dz dx= \int_0^1\frac{y}{x}dx$$
$$=y(ln(1)-ln(0))$$
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question!

You are correct, under the conditions given
$$P(Y<y)= \int_0^1P(Y<y|X=x)dx$$
The next question is to find $P(Y<y|X=x)$, and it is easy to show that it is equal to $y/x$ but (!) only if $y<x$; generally
\begin{equation}
P(Y<y|X=x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{x}, &\text{if 0<y<x}\\
1,  &\text{if y>x}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Now,

$$P(Y<y)= \int_0^1P(Y<y|X=x)dx=\int_0^y1dx+\int_y^1\frac{y}{x}dx=y(1-\ln y)$$

Answer (score 0):

first step should be
$$
P(Y<y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(Y<y, X=x)f_{X}(x)dx
$$
except you cannot use $X =x$ for continuous variables, but instead use it's $\epsilon$-analog...

Comment: I'm kind of confused and can't see why my first step is wrong and yours is right.